# Flash AS3: isometric grid movement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Really desperate help needed for this Flash AS3 question. I am currently creating a game similar to cafe world, farmville etc (social game). Would like to know how could i make an object move in an isometric direction when my mouse move. 
For example, when I want to build a house, i click on the house build button, and when my mouse move, I want my house object (stored in the library) to be move together with my mouse in an isometric direction. To give you all a better impression of the solution i am looking for, click on this link for a sketch: http://www.flickr.com/photos/58743938@N07/5497636770/

So i want something like only when my mouse move 20 units more than the original mouse position, then my house item should move to the next grid.

Do clarify with me if there's anything that is unclear. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to explore as3isolib... http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/

There's a nice introduction here... http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=136

What you are looking at is probably something like this though...

```
house.x = Math.floor(this.mouseX/SQUARE_SIZE)*SQUARE_SIZE;
house.y = Math.floor(this.mouseY/SQUARE_SIZE)*SQUARE_SIZE;
```

You might need to do some globalToLocal or vice versa for the mouse position, plus an offset for the grid etc.

Comment: thanks for your help :) as my team is purely coding from inside flash, somehow, when we use as3isolib, no error returns but we can't see anything (when we are playing ard with the tutorials from as3isolib)... your 2 statements do help a bit , but we are still quite stuck.. :( is it possible to give us more guide to it? (sry, we are really new to all this! :p )

Comment: btw, I've tried another way and its like its almost there but its still not really always snapping to the grid... Also, its moving way too fast! Any solutions? :) you can view the flash file here: https://www.yousendit.com/download/T2pHcXlqQzd1Yk94dnc9PQ

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest you break your code out of the flash IDE (FlashDevelop is free), the time you spend learning how to structure your code into classes will be regained later in the project when debugging and adding features.

Comment: To get what you currently have working. Make sure all your registration points are where they are for a reason. Select all the squares in your grid and position them as a whole at 0,0. And then position the grid itself at 0,0. Centre your land asset (eg. -40,-20). In your CheckDirection function add the following landBlue.x=Math.floor(this.mouseX/40)*40 + 20;
landBlue.y=Math.floor(this.mouseY/20)*20 + 10;  and remove calls to GetHorizontalDirection and GetVerticalDirection

Comment: OMGGGGG~ Thanks a lot Trevor!!! its WORKING!!!!!!! whee!!! you are like our saviour for our project haha! thanks pal! :D

Comment: oh, and yeap, we understand that breaking the code out of flash IDE is impt but due to time constraint, its a bit hard to convert all the codes to .as files... Tried it for a few days last time, but was rather stuck! :p but really thanks a lot for the kind help! :)